# Android video encoding and deocding native level

Tags: android, video, encoding, android-ndk, decoding

**Scenario** :
I have to read the video frames  and edit them and encode it a new .mp4 file.
According to the research i have done i can do this native level. Even if i am doing it in the native level which open source library i can use so that the encoding and decoding of the video will be faster. It have seen in many places people used ffmpeg but it in order to H264 stream it needs LGPL license. Is there any other libraries which have better performance and comes under GPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use Android 4.3 (API 18) or greater, take a look to the [Big Flake samples](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#samples). It's easy to rewrite them to your needs.

If you want other API version, you will have to compile and use [FFMPEG for Android](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android)